# Looking for example of DocuSign REST API v2 Post Envelope Correction and can this change the emailSubject?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am looking for an example of the DocuSign REST API v2 Post Envelope Correction and wanted to know how this works and if it will change the emailSubject of a draft envelope. Essentially, I am creating a draft envelope with a default emailSubject (required field) and then adding documents and recipients and now I want to be able to change the emailSubject, emailBlurb, etc. values of the envelope. The online documentation does not elaborate on the requirements for this API call.

Answer (score 0):

In V2 (the currently released version) you can't update the email subject.  In V3 (currently going through development) those features are added.  I am happy to work with you on a creative solution to your particular problem.  Depending on the go-live date for your project you might also be able to time it right, we can whitelist your app to access V3 with all usual disclaimers of accessing pre-released software.

Comment: We have not set a "go live" date yet. Also, given the problems we have encountered so far, we are not even sure this will work for us. I am interested in checking out your V3 with the understanding that this is re-release software.

Comment: Are you in touch with a sales engineer. Every time people say 'we are not sure it will work for us' I think the best next step is to actually take a holistic view of what they are trying to do. Let me know if you need help with that. Stack overflow is not set up for long discussions.

Comment: We are a ColdFusion shop and so we are trying to use CFHTTP to communicate with DocuSign using the REST API. We have had success in all areas except editing draft envelopes, as mentioned above, and deleting Recipients, Documents and Tabs. We have also been unable to create an envelope from a document directly, but we can create a draft envelope and then add documents, recipients and tabs. If we can't delete then we can't use DocuSign.

Comment: Chuck - are you in touch with a DocuSign Account Manager?  Who is it?  I'd like to make sure your voice is heard.

Comment: I've just been in touch with Michael Hunt, Account Manager and Steve Park, Technician(?). They are looking into these issues and will get back to me. I appreciate your efforts. I am very interested in learning more about the features in V3 since it appears that V2 will not suit our needs.